# How does `_setmode` in Visual Studio's CRT interact with `std::wcout`?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

According to ["Conventional Wisdom is Wrong"](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx), the CRT does a fair bit of work in order to smooth out inconsistencies in the handling of Unicode in the console on Win32 if an appropriate flag is set on `stdout`. However, I'm not using `cstdio` style functions here -- I'm using the `iostream`s library. How does `_setmode` interact with the standard streams `std::wcout`, `std::wclog`, and `std::wcerr` (if at all?). If it is not usable with the streams, then is it possible/how would one get equivalent behavior?

Answers which work for either VS2008 or VS2010 will work -- I'm not worried about anything earlier than that.

Comment: Yuck.  setlocale() matters for iostream.

Comment: Relevant FAQ indicating that the answer will be highly environment specific: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.13

Comment: Also related, but rather inconclusive: http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.languages.vc/browse_thread/thread/1275313963d6f67e

Comment: @Hans: Yes, what I'm talking about is not standard C++. It's a MSVC specific extension which correctly handles unicode output no matter what the output is, be it a file or the console. I'm not aware of doing this via any means via `setlocale()`. Of course, if it is possible, I would much prefer a standards compliant solution.

Comment: You are talking about wprintf(), not iostream.  MS adopted what passes as 'standard' for the iostream classes.  'Standard' and setlocale otherwise are rarely seen in one sentence, it's rather a mess.  A couple of things you want to avoid when you write console mode apps.  Like doing anything resembling graphics.  And trying to get fancy with text.  Your next debacle is the console font.

Comment: @Hans: I don't think proper unicode support is "trying to get fancy with text". I can work around this by calling Win32 APIs myself. But if the CRT already does the right thing, it would be nice to not have to reinvent the wheel. Yes, `wprintf` is also an msvc specific extension, but the `_setmode()` call mentioned in the article is applied to `stdout`, which makes it reasonable to assume that there might be a method to make the iostreams behave the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, from memory. There was a question I answered a long time ago now where wprintf() would print correctly but wcout<< wouldn't.

Comment: Any idea how to get equivalent behavior then?

Comment: @Billy: Despite some extensive efforts, I couldn't get his wcout to print correctly in all cases.